# Overriding Mule flows' classes

Tags: java, mule

I have requirement to customize Synchronous UntilSuccessful scope with an ObjectStore. But I could not, because below exception is thrown:

`Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Until successful cannot be configured to be synchronous and use an object store.
    at org.mule.routing.SynchronousUntilSuccessfulProcessingStrategy.initialise(SynchronousUntilSuccessfulProcessingStrategy.java:75)`.

It is apparent that the **initialise()** method of **SynchronousUntilSuccessfulProcessingStrategy** class throws this exception.

So I have overridden this method with dummy implementation by extending **SynchronousUntilSuccessfulProcessingStrategy** class, say for example the extended class is **ObjectStoreAwareSynchronousUntilSuccessful**.

Now my question is, how can I intstruct the Mule flows to look at my extended class rather than the original class?

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `custom-router` or `custom-processor` and set the class attribute. Similar here using a Spring bean: [Exposing class attributes to JMX for Mule custom router: what are my options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967460/exposing-class-attributes-to-jmx-for-mule-custom-router-what-are-my-options)

Comment: Tried creating custom-router/custom-processor using the link you provided, could not make it work. Appreciate if you share running sample code.